# How can i make this statistic query dynamic?

Tags: java, mysql

I have this user table:

```
id(int) | created (datetime)
```

I'm showing statistics on a server which does following:
- You choose a date
- You choose if you want to show daily, weekly or monthly statistics (see query)

I have made the query very static by just doing it like this:

```
WEEK(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -2 WEEK) // Shows how many users that has been created from two weeks before current date to current date
```

Now i want the admin that should look at the statistic to be able to choose how far back in time he wants to show statistics from. 
So i need to make the query dynamic.

**Here is the original static query i have made:**

```
String sQuery = "SELECT " +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created) as totalNumberOfCreatedUsers, " +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(" + date + ") = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysNumberOfCreatedUsers, " +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusOneNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -2 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusTwoNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -3 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusThreeNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -4 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusFourNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -5 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusFiveNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -6 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusSixNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -7 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusSevenNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE WEEK(" + date + ") = WEEK(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisWeeksNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE WEEK(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -1 WEEK)) = WEEK(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisWeeksMinusOneNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE WEEK(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -2 WEEK)) = WEEK(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisWeeksMinusTwoNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE WEEK(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -3 WEEK)) = WEEK(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisWeeksMinusThreeNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE WEEK(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -4 WEEK)) = WEEK(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisWeeksMinusFourNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(" + date + ") = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusOneNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -2 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusTwoNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -3 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusThreeNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -4 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusFourNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -5 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusFiveNumberOfCreatedUsers," +
                "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE MONTH(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -6 MONTH)) = MONTH(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created))  as thisMonthsMinusSixNumberOfCreatedUsers" +
                "";
```

e.g: 
One solution i could do (java): (But this would create a large query, and i want a more efficient way to do it)  (btw, this example is not working code, just something i thought of to give you and idea of what a solution could be)

---

The admin chooses to see 20 days/weeks/months

```
String addToQuery = "";
int daysWeeksMonthsToLookBack = inputFromUser // inputFromUser = 20 in this example
for(int i=0; i<daysWeeksMonthsToLookBack; i++){
  addToQuery += "       (SELECT count(statistic_customer_created.id) FROM statistic_customer_created WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(" + date + ", INTERVAL -" + i + " DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(statistic_customer_created.created) AND YEAR(" + date + ") = YEAR(statistic_customer_created.created)) as thisDaysMinusFiveNumberOfCreatedUsers," +

}
```

Anyone got a suggestion how i can do this more efficiently?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just group by the day and add the single days on the java side of things?

Comment: I can't really see how that is going to help me make the query dynamic. Are you suggesting that i use the for loop from java side, and just group by day in the query?

Answer (score 1):

I would have used a range like

```
SELECT count(s.id) 
FROM statistic_customer_created s
WHERE s.created >= {date calculated in Java}
```

By taking the difference of these dates you can get all those created between 1 and 2 days ago.

The count for those created in the last 7 days and those created in the last week should be the same.

Comment: hmmm, but since i need to get statistic from date - 1, date - 2 etc.... it will still be a large query. Even if i calculate the date in java....

Comment: Its large if you do it all at once. I would do the above query in a loop, but that might be slower. You could build the query in a StringBuilder in a loop.

Comment: yep, that was my thoughts too, i just wanted to see if anybody else had a better tip, how to do it dynamically in sql